# builtins.TypeError: invalid file: <Response [200]> wile reading xml file - python

Tags: python, xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as reader
import requests

web_data = 'http://api.worldbank.org/incomeLevels/LIC/countries'
a = requests.get(web_data)
print(a.headers['Content-Type'])
print(reader.parse(a).getroot())
```

It looks this method doesn't work, it returns me builtins.TypeError: invalid file:  despite "content-type returns xml data. any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the line:

```
print(reader.parse(a).getroot())
```

to

```
print(reader.fromstring(a.text))
```

the a is the response object, a.text is the content.

Also, `reader.parse()` expect a filename, if you wanto to parse from a string you have to use the [fromstring](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) method.

Note that the fromstring method already return the root element of your xml.